# How to open PDF in PDFsharp where PDF is added as a resource to the project

Tags: vb.net, pdf, vb.net-2010, pdfsharp

I'm getting an error in the path because it's retrieving `System.Byte[]` in it. How can I access the PDF which is added in my resources?

Code:

```
PdfDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(My.Resources.CANEezz_Individual.ToString, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)

Dim font9 As XFont = New XFont("Arial", 8)
Dim page As PdfPage = PdfDocument.Pages(0)
Dim graph As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
graph.DrawString("Bank Passboook", font9, XBrushes.Black, 518, 343)

Dim pdfFilename As String = "something.pdf"
PdfDocument.Save(pdfFilename)
Process.Start(pdfFilename)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `byte[]` to the constructor of `MemoryStream` and pass that memory stream to the `PdfReader.Open()` method.

Comment: Dim ss As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(My.Resources.CANEezz_Individual)

        pdfDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(ss, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)

Made these changes and it works for me 
ty :)